# Knot Group and the Unknot

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, low-dimensional-topology, knot-invariants

Hi I am stuck in trying to show that given a knot $K$ such that the knot group $\pi_1(K)=\mathbb Z$ then $K\simeq U$.

I tried to use the fact that the infinite cyclic cover is the universal cover but I don't know if that is the right way.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: As @janmarqz points out, you probably meant $\pi_1(S^3\setminus K)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need some tools of 3-manifold topology --- the loop theorem and the generalized Schönflies theorem --- in order to prove this (assuming you mean $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus K)$.

Consider the manifold $M$ obtained from $S^3$ by removing an open solid torus neighborhood of $K$, so $\partial M$ is homeomorphic to $T^2$. The inclusion induced homomorphism 
$$\mathbb{Z}^2 \approx \pi_1(T^2) \mapsto \pi_1(M) \approx \mathbb{Z}
$$
is not injective.

Applying the [loop theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_theorem), there exists a tamely embedded 2-disc $D \subset M$ such that $D \cap \partial M = \partial D$ and that circle is nontrivial in the torus $\partial M$. It follows that the boundary of a regular neighborhood of $D \cup \partial M$ is a tamely embedded 2-sphere $S^2 \hookrightarrow M \subset S^3$.

Applying the [generalized Schönflies theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem), that 2-sphere is standard, after composing with a self-homeomorphicm of $S^3$ we may assume that this is **the** usual embedding of $S^2$ in $S^3$.

From this it follows that $K$ is the unknot.

Comment: I don't see why you need the Schönflies theorem. You can just use the theorem that a knot is the unknot iff it bounds a disk, which is much weaker than Schönflies. (Just use the disk itself to guide an isotopy into a small ball where the disk is very close to flat and the knot is obviously standard.)

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: In your scenario, you still have to prove that an embedded disc is ambient isotopic to a standard disc.

Comment: Well, I'm not quite using that. I'm saying use the disk you have (which a priori could be knotted) to contract the knot along until it bounds a small subdisk of the original disk. (This uses the isotopy extension theorem.) Then this disk is close to flat so there is an obvious isotopy to a flat disk by projection onto, say, the tangent plane at an interior point. Then the knot is clearly a standard unknot. Your argument is fine, it just seemed like overkill.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip : $\:$ Why would the disk necessarily be close to flat? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: I'm assuming it's a smooth disk, which is no loss of generality in 3D. Then it is well approximated by its tangent plane near a point. (Probably this is proven using the implicit function theorem.)

Answer (score 5):

Note: I am assuming the OP is referring to the usual knot group $\pi_1(S^3\setminus K)$. That's the only way his second sentence makes sense anyway.

There is a curve on the boundary torus which is null-homotopic in the complement, since the inclusion of the boundary into the complement is $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ on $\pi_1$. This means that the boundary torus is not incompressible. So there is a simple closed curve on the torus that bounds a disk into the complement. Furthermore, the only such curve which is null-homologous is the longitude. Therefore, the longitude is null-homotopic and by the disk theorem bounds an embedded disk. Thus the knot is the unknot.

Answer (score 1):

For any knot $K$ you always have $\pi_1(K)=\Bbb Z$ because any knot is homeomorphic to the circle. The major trouble comes when one considers the complement of the knot and depending where is embedded.

Comment: take a look at the wiki version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_group

Comment: mr downvoter, strictlysymbolicallyspeaking $\pi_1(X)$ means the 1st homotopy-group-of-the-space $X$, forgetmeifmyresponse hurts you :P